# Time to Say Goodbye - Henders

Tags: discussion, moderators

### Dearest Pets Community,

It is with a genuinely heavy heart that **I am to resign my position as Moderator of Pets Stack Exchange**. It staggers me to see that my joining date for this site is already 4 years ago and that I've been a moderator for 2 years 7 months (nearly 1000 days).

Ever since I joined Pets I felt that it was unique. Our little site deals with some of our fondest friends whether they have fur, feathers, scales, gills, antenna or any number of other characteristics from the euphoric highs to difficult lows. I feel extremely lucky to have shared in the lives of so many of this communities Pets whether it be Ash's park walks, Trine's outdoor adventures or the cutest pig I've ever seen.

Pets gives you that rare opportunity to help an animal (and human) on the other side of the planet which is struggling to communicate the issues it is having. If I've managed to improve the life of one Pet (especially a first fish) then I'll consider this venture a success.

Recent events have shifted my impression of Stack Exchange. I hope that in the future our ideals once again align but my circumstances have changed and I have less time and energy to devote to what looks like a rocky road ahead. I leave with my memories of the successes we've shared, the knowledge we've collated and the friendships I've formed. The current moderator team has been doing all the heavy lifting perfectly well without me for a few months so you're all in great hands.

I'd like to thank James, Yvette and Rebecca whom I began this journey with and continued to work so hard with me to improve this tiny corner of the internet. Additionally, every other mod who has helped, advised and made me laugh in the Teacher's Lounge. Finally, the whole of that invariably hardworking CM team and specifically Tim, Catija, Shog and Jon Ericson. I am richer for your guidance and support.

To the community - you make this all possible. Keep being awesome <3

Until we meet again,

**Henders**.

Comment: It's with ambivalence I upvote this post, as I don't want to see you go, but ofc you've been a great mod xo

Answer (score 12):

Well my dear friend, it doesn't seem that long ago that we were discussing the possibility of you becoming a mod and what a great mod you've been indeed.

The doors are always open for you to return. We will miss you, but it's understandable. Life waxes and wanes and our journeys meander down different paths.

Take care in these difficult global times of COVID-19.

Again, you've been an exemplar moderator.
Take care,
much love and warmth
xoxoxo

Comment: Thanks, Yvette, It's been an absolute pleasure - I'll see you around I'm sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late, but goodbye Henders, I'm sure you were a great mod and best of luck to you mate. I thank you for helping this site so much and Pets.SE are always here for you buddy.

Comment: Why did you answer this?

Comment: Thanks for your kind words :)