# Time to say goodbye - one less moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

At the writing of this post I am a moderator and the second highest ranking contributor on this site.

I'm leaving the network. I've requested to have my accounts deleted and want to move on with my life. I no longer enjoy this network. Not so much this site, but Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

I am leaving this note here, as there's so many lovely people here and I owe them an explanation. With James not wanting to sign the new moderator agreement, the site will only be left with one moderator. [James losing mod privileges Sept 7](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/james-losing-mod-privileges-sept-7)

I was a founding member of this community and it has been interesting. I no longer believe in the ethos of the company and I do not like how the Meta sites are run on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. Very little has changed since I first joined the network in 2012 despite having a rigorous Code of Conduct. It seems to be applied subjectively. I also do not want to continue making voluntary contributions to a site that makes money off the back of those contributions and does little to support the contributors.

I hope you and all your pets are healthy and safe during these strange global times.

Thank you for giving me the honour to serve you on this site, it's been a pleasure.

My YouTube account is temporarily hidden as I have been faced with a legal suit and need to protect our interests (nothing to do with the network). When that is over, I will unhide it and the people who follow me on there can contact me through the comments.

Take care xx

Love all our horses, dog and cats
*neigh neigh, woof, meow purr.*

Comment: Yvette, I came to Pets today because I got some rep (on 3 posts) and reread the answer you gave me in a time of great concern over my Belgian Tervuren puppy. Your answer was so thorough that I was able to get the vet to investigate my puppy more thoroughly, leading to the correct diagnosis (pyloric stenosis) and treatment. Your contributions to me, an infrequent visitor, were/are invaluable; thank you! You will be fondly remembered and missed. Take care. (I understand, though. I also resigned for the exact same reasons.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I'm sincerely glad I could help. There's a frightening amount of misinformation on the internet, that is akin to the "old wives tales" that human beings have clung to for centuries. I was a vigilante in trying to combat misinformation with good information, but it's exhausting. All the meta fallout is exhausting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an original beta participant, but admittedly much less frequent in recent years, I'm sorry to see you go.  You were an expert in a site that needed experts because there is a lot of bad information on pets.

I frequently disagreed with you on SO, but here on Pets, I never disagreed with your expertise.  You were a great resource here and your contributions will (hopefully) continue to exist for a long while.  And as a moderator, I always felt your efforts were fair and unbiased.

Good luck on your future endeavors.

Comment: Thank  you. It's the end of an era and much of it is due to the success of the network and the way its business model has developed. It's in stark contrast to a community driven site and the two will never be fully reconciled. It's a shame. I will miss this site, but I cannot tolerate this network any longer. Everyone who has been around for a long time understands this stress. I mean the network has lost so many long term users and high end contributors. It's time to just focus on my pets and not worry about this cyber existence. :) Take care xx