# What next for the Pets Community?

Tags: discussion, moderators

In a month, Pets.SE is going to have one or fewer [moderators](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Unless there is some change, [I will be losing mod privileges](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/james-losing-mod-privileges-sept-7). Harry V. has not declared his intentions and [Yvette is already gone](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/time-to-say-goodbye-one-less-moderator).

If the site does not have moderators, SE will close it, all of the posts and the site https://pets.stackexchange.com/ will be gone.

To continue there are two options, neither or both can occur, they are **NOT** mutually exclusive.

1. **Migrate to [codidact](https://codidact.com/)**. Many SE communities have migrated to codidact. Some people are exclusively participating in the codidact version of the community, while others continue to participate in both codidact and SE. I personally, will gladly support and assist anyone who wants to lead a drive to migrate/copy content from Pets.SE to Pets.codidact.com. I do not have the energy to lead the drive.
2. **Elect new Moderators**, personally I find it impossible to speak positively about pursuing this option. If any members of the community want to do this you are welcome to create a new meta post.  I strongly recommend that anyone involved, be familiar with [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and understand the history over the last couple of years.  Additionally, understand that being a moderator in a pets community is emotionally difficult.  We love our pets or we would not be here, moderating some posts can be very difficult.

Comment: Well - while I'm certain there's better candidates, I would probably stand if there is another election if I am able. I'm sure there might be others. Small communities like this are the heart of what I feel SE ought to be about.

Answer (score 11):

Pets.SE will not be left without any moderators. The site is not going to close.

I intend to accept the new moderator agreement in due course. There are certainly actions by SE over the past few years that I am less than pleased with, but I truly want this community to continue to succeed.

I have been in private communication with SE and they are working on a plan to find more help to moderate Pets. Obviously I do not want to be the only moderator here indefinitely, but also recognise that finding new moderators is not something that should be rushed.

Comment: +1 You have my best wishes for continued support of the community here.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Some communities have survived with one moderator for quite a while, others have officially three, but neither is on the site daily and we had CMs jump in with some flags. In the end, it hinges on the community. If enough regular users are willing (and able, rep-wise) to do community moderation, it will work out. If not, more moderators won’t be the crucial factor, IMHO. A lot of older Betas were promoted not much before a well-known series of events, and now there’s quite a bit of a backlog of pending elections. Pets is probably pretty far towards the end of this queue.